# could not connect /dev/video0 (webcam), what should i do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am working in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - Lucid Lynx.
My notebook is Samsung r720 with internal livewebcam (webcam SCB-1600).
I have installed ubuntu all was ok, but a couple week ago my WebCam stoped to work.

When i tried to run camorama i have got "Could not connect to video (/dev/video0) Please check connection".

I checked on windows, all is working.

What i have to do to fix it?

```
ls -la /dev/video0 
andrew@andrew-laptop:~ $ ls -la /dev/video0
ls: can not access /dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: you can simply run sudo chmod 777 /dev/video0 if have just fix issue in my system

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any other video device (maybe just `video`, or `video1`: `ls -la /dev/video*`)?

If you haven't any other device, it most likely means your webcam isn't supported by your kernel. You should install (or load) the kernel modules (ie: drivers) for it.

Comment: ls -la /dev/video* - the same, but i should note that my web-cam was working, i don't know why it stopped.